# Pandas - groupby "longest" duration of Paid Time Off (PTO)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas frame with employee PTO entries:

```
employee_id time_off_date
1           1/1/2017
1           1/2/2017
1           1/3/2017
1           5/1/2017
2           6/1/2017
2           9/5/2017
2           9/6/2017
2           9/7/2017
2           9/8/2017
```

I am trying to find the longest duration of consecutive days of PTO each employee took.  For example, employee #1's longest PTO duration is 3 days (1/1/2017 to 1/3/2017) and employee #2's longest PTO duration is 4 days (9/5/2017 to 9/8/2017).

I'm a bit stumped on what combination of pandas `groupby` and `shift` I should use to answer this question.

Bonus points: find all PTO durations for all employees over X days.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I suppose one could `iterrows` over the grouped employee IDs but this doesn't seem very efficient (aka "iterating over the pandas, kills the pandas").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `diff` with `cumsum` create subgruop within each employee_id, then we do `groupby` `size` with `max` to find the max

```
s=df.groupby('employee_id').time_off_date.apply(lambda x : x.diff().dt.days.ne(1).cumsum())
df['New']=s
df.groupby(['employee_id','New']).size().max(level=0)
Out[423]: 
employee_id
1    3
2    4
dtype: int64
```

Comment: `df.groupby('employee_id')['time_off_date'].apply(lambda x: x.groupby(x.diff().dt.days.ne(1).cumsum()).count()).max(level=0)`

Comment: Damn, that is some sexy a$$ python.  Thanks guys.